# Direction vector of tangent line to a sphere.

Tags: geometry

I want to know how we can find the direction vector of a line tangent to a sphere.
Like for example

Consider the sphere passing through the point P(2,-1,3) and with center C(1,2,-3) Find the parametric equation of the line tangent to sphere at point P.( you need to first  have the direction vector)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There is an infinite number of convenient  tangent lines.

Comment: Find the tangent plane at the point, then any line in that plane will do. The gradient of the surface at P will give the normal vector to this plane